# Have mysql error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

trying write in console command to enable my script and get this error:

```
rails@survey:~$ rails-run-script survey mossad_sync
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `real_connect': Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (Mysql::Error)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:620:in `connect'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:203:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/mysql_adapter.rb:75:in `mysql_connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `send'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:223:in `new_connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:245:in `checkout_new_connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:188:in `checkout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `loop'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:184:in `checkout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:183:in `checkout'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:98:in `connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:326:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:123:in `retrieve_connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:115:in `connection'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:3166:in `quoted_table_name'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1718:in `construct_finder_sql'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:1582:in `find_every'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.11/lib/active_record/base.rb:619:in `find'
    from lib/scripts/hello_sync.rb:4
```

What i should fix? I check my production connection in database.yml, there are no bugs (host, user, pw I already wrote)

Comment: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost', check that user and password is correct and have permission on db

Answer (score 0):

It cannot connect to MySQL, but you knew that didn't you ;)

```
mysql -u root -p
```

That should give you the same error. [Make sure that the `root` user is allowed to login from `localhost`](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/788/HOWTO%3A+GRANT+privileges+in+MySQL#dv). Maybe you can change `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`? Have you entered the correct password?

Comment: hmm it is strange, in database.yml (ruby) i wrote my table name and wrote databsae name , username, password and so on, BUT STILL NOTHING.. still this error

Comment: Yes, i changed host, password is correct :S and i have another mistake =>> Mysql::Error: SELECT command denied to user 'baza_survey'@'surv' for table 'respondent_groups': SELECT * FROM `respondent_groups`  (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid) ...
What does whit mistake means? In my code something;s wrong or admin didnt give me permisions?

Comment: As the error says `SELECT command denied to user 'baza_survey'`. You're mysql user doesn't have the necessary permissions.